# How is infect a fair mechanic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Thee infect mechanic from Scars of Mirrodin has never seemed fair to me in any way.

All of the game's win conditions have always been equally difficult to achieve: dealing 20 damage, milling an entire library down, or meeting the conditions for one of the other win cards, like Battle of Wits, etc. All of them take a fair amount of time, none are much faster than the others really.

But with infect, you only have to deal 10 damage. It renders the normal life totals pointless. I have trouble thinking of it as some special win-condition when all it really means is that "dealing 10 damage is enough to win," and you can just ignore life totals.

I don't see how infect is considered fair or balanced. Can someone maybe give me some insight as to why it doesn't get more backlash from the community?

Prior to Scars of Mirrodin, there were so few creatures with it that it was hard to achieve a victory that way. Scars of Mirrodin changed that, hence my present confusion.

Comment: Infect is from the Scars of Mirrodin block. And only from that block.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Editing.

Comment: It's just that regarding your last paragraph, there was no Infect printed before Scars, or after.

Comment: Yes there was. See serpent generator and crypt cobra. Same thing in principal.

Comment: The very important difference between Infect and triggered abilities that give poison counters is that the latter are not affected by pumping the creature. Those abilities and Poisonous are basically worthless.

Comment: Good point! Again hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Keep in mind, it was a card with poisonous that completely and utterly broke Two-Headed Giant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infect isn't just "dealing 10 damage is enough to win". It's "dealing 10 damage *with creatures with Infect* is enough to win," which means that you have to go all-in on Infect to do well with it. This means that Infect decks are very creature heavy and are very vulnerable to board wipes; a single [Terminus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Terminus) can set you back several turns.

Infect creatures are also generally easier to remove than other creatures. A total of 4 Infect creatures have abilities that make them more difficult to remove: [Blightsteel Colossus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blightsteel%20Colossus), [Skithiryx, the Blight Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skithiryx%2C%20the%20Blight%20Dragon), [Tel-Jilad Fallen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tel-Jilad%20Fallen), and [Toxic Nim](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Toxic%20Nim). Every Infect creature can be removed with [Path to Exile](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Path%20to%20Exile), and most can be killed with [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt).

Plus, besides [Blighted Agent](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blighted%20Agent), Infect creatures can be blocked like any other. My 2/2 Infect for 3, like [Contagious Nim](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Contagious%20Nim), still trades with your [Grizzly Bears](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grizzly%20Bears). And that extra mana can make the difference. By turn 4 or 5, the player not playing Infect should have creatures that are bigger than the player playing Infect. And attacking into a group of larger creatures still ends up with your creatures dead, even if they did have Infect.

Overall, cheap Infect creatures with cheap pump spells can get close to victory shockingly fast. But they can also be stopped by cheap removal and countermagic.

---

[Blightsteel Colossus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blightsteel%20Colossus) is a special case: it costs so much that Infect decks don't play it; instead it's mostly played as another win condition in decks that can cheat creatures onto the battlefield, and those also play other ridiculously powerful creatures like [Griselbrand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Griselbrand), [Iona, Shield of Emeria](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Iona%2C%20Shield%20of%20Emeria), and [Emrakul, the Aeons Torn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Emrakul%2C%20the%20Aeons%20Torn).

Comment: (When was blightsteel colossus aforementioned? Just curious if I'm missing something.) Also, thanks for the answer, I suppose this is a fairly valid point.

Comment: Oh, right, I reordered the answer

Comment: Yup. It's really only access to powerful pump spells that makes Infect viable in Constructed at all. They're rather below-curve otherwise.

Comment: @Aerovistae The other way to look at it is just that if it were as overpowered as you suggest in the question, no one would bother attacking for normal damage. But pretty much the only decks that kill with infect in Modern are affinity (which also kills with normal damage) and the dedicated infect deck.